# Nginx: could not build map_hash, you should increase map_hash_bucket_size: 64

Tags: nginx, configuration, hash, sizing

I need to use redirect map with quite a lot rules (2k+ lines, file size is ~200K)

I have the following settings in nginx:

```
map $uri $new_uri {
        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/redirects.map;
}

server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        # redirects
        if ($new_uri) {
                rewrite ^ $new_uri permanent;
        }
```

as described [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-nginx-s-map-module-on-ubuntu-16-04) and found [here](https://easyengine.io/wordpress-nginx/tutorials/multisite/static-files-handling/). The problem : configtest fails:

```
nginx: [emerg] could not build map_hash, you should increase map_hash_bucket_size: 64
```

I tried to increase map_hash_max_size and map_hash_bucket_size to quite crazy values:

```
map $uri $new_uri {
        map_hash_max_size 262144;
        map_hash_bucket_size 262144;
        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/redirects.map;
}
```

but still have the same error (ending exactly with '64'). I selected those values so they are bigger than the file size. I made sure I'm editing live config by adding "blabla" and see 'unknown directive'

So, how those values should be set? There's not much details [in the official doc](http://nginx.org/en/docs/hash.html), unfortunately.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`map_hash_max_size` and `map_hash_bucket_size` must be in `http` context, i.e. outside of `map` directive.

```
map_hash_max_size 262144;
map_hash_bucket_size 262144;
map $uri $new_uri {
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/redirects.map;
}
```

Comment: I set up right above the map but still got the same error. It's really weird.

Comment: @KevinNguyen what error?

Comment: Nginx: could not build map_hash, you should increase map_hash_bucket_size: 64. I posted my answer btw.

Comment: It is not obvious but it also needs to appear _before_ the `map` directives.

Comment: @AlexeyTen this solution works well in with nginx 1.16 but not with nginx 1.18.

Answer (score 2):

I put it on the top of the http {} and it worked. Don't put it outside http {}

Answer (score 1):

Add to the top of the `http` block in the main configuration file (`/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`):

```
map_hash_bucket_size 128;
```

Comment: How does your answer differ from the existing answer?

Comment: I got the following error: `nginx: "map_hash_bucket_size" directive is duplicate in /etc/nginx/conf.d/my-redirect-map.conf:2` using the above answer. This answer indicates that `map_hash_max_size` is not required and this global setting is better suited to be placed in the main configuration file.

Comment: Well, having it twice in your config causes that problem.

Comment: Yip. Another reason why it is better to put this setting in the main nginx config.